# $\log(x^2)$ is not equal to $2\log(x)$

Tags: logarithms

on internet we usually see:
$$2\log(x) = \log(x^2) $$
([example](https://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/logarithm/Logarithm_Rules.html#power%20rule))but how is this true? one is defined for $x>0$ and the other one for $x\neq0$

Comment: One ought to write $\log (x^2)=2\log |x|$.

Comment: That identity holds for positive real x, in the same way as $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ holds only for $x \ge 0$, or $1/(1/x) = x$ holds only for $x \ne 0$.

Comment: Fun fact: $1\ne\frac{x}{x}$

Comment: You can have two functions defined on different domains, which coincide on the intersection of their domains.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Wolfram Alpha calculating this incorrectly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1339442/42969)

Comment: In the reals , this identity is valid since it only makes sense anyway in the case $x>0$. We cannot compare something that is not defined with anything else (not even with something undefined as well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assertion $\log(x^2)=2\log(x)$ and similar expressions usually means that we have that equality when both the LHS and RHS are defined. It's like the equality$$\frac1{1/x}=x.\tag1\label1$$The LHS is undefined when $x=0$, whereas the RHS is defined for every number. And asserting that $\eqref1$ holds means, in this case, that it holds when $x\ne0$.

Comment: thank you, sorry but this was in one of the prof solutions and he passed from $log((t-1)^2)$ to $log((1-t)^2)$